# TypeError: unsubFirebaseSnapShot01 is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a web app with React.

On the Home screen, I've the following code. 
When running the app, it throws **TypeError: unsubFirebaseSnapShot01 is not a function.**

[browser console error screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEUXY.png)

These are the only references to these functions in `index.js`:

```
let unsubFirebaseSnapShot01;
let unsubFirebaseSnapShot02;
let unsubFirebaseSnapShot03;

...

class Home extends Component {

...

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
    unsubFirebaseSnapShot01();
    unsubFirebaseSnapShot02();
    unsubFirebaseSnapShot03();
  }

  checkAll = () => {
    this.checkMeetingsSetByMe();
    this.checkMeetingsSetForMe();
    this.checkNotifications();
  };

  checkMeetingsSetByMe = () => {
    if (!this.mounted) return;
    const {
      user: { uid },
    } = this.props;
    this.setState({ screenLoading: true });

    unsubFirebaseSnapShot01 = Meetings.where('setBy', '==', uid).onSnapshot(
      ({ docs }) => {
        // setting all the meetingsSetByMe in one place
        const meetingsSetByMe = docs.map(item => item.data());
        if (this.mounted);
        this.setState({ meetingsSetByMe, screenLoading: false });
      },
    );
  };

  checkMeetingsSetForMe = () => {
    if (!this.mounted) return;
    const {
      user: { uid },
    } = this.props;
    this.setState({ screenLoading: true });

    unsubFirebaseSnapShot02 = Meetings.where('setWith', '==', uid).onSnapshot(
      ({ docs }) => {
        // setting all the meetingsSetForMe in one place
        const meetingsSetForMe = docs.map(item => item.data());
        if (this.mounted);
        this.setState({ meetingsSetForMe, screenLoading: false });
      },
    );
  };

  checkNotifications = () => {
    if (!this.mounted) return;
    const {
      user: { uid },
    } = this.props;
    this.setState({ screenLoading: true });

    unsubFirebaseSnapShot03 = Meetings.where('status', '==', 'unseen')
      .where('setWith', '==', uid)
      .onSnapshot(({ docs }) => {
        const notifications = docs.map(item => item.data());
        if (this.mounted);
        this.setState({ notifications, screenLoading: false });
      });
  };
```

Double checked any typos but cannot see my mistake. 
Any help?

Comment: remove () in variables in componentWillUnmount function

Comment: doing that throws `Line 120:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

Comment: Why do you call 
    unsubFirebaseSnapShot01();
    unsubFirebaseSnapShot02();
    unsubFirebaseSnapShot03();
are those functions ? if not try to remove it from component will mount

Comment: yea, they unmount the firebase requests. if they are not called the loading screen goes in a infinite loop